# Accelerometer freak out

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer

I am testing my app, and i am meant to be getting the readings from the accelometer...pretty simple! right now , the code says, if the acceleration is above 0.005, start adding 1 to a value... however for some reason, when i rotate the ipad, , so it seems to be 'standing on one of its edges' like a diamond, the value seems to be increasing? it increases even if the ipad is completely still. 
Here is the code :

```
motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.02
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data,error) in
    if let myData = data {
        if myData.acceleration.y > 0.05 {      
            self.damian += 1
            print(data)
        }
```

Comment: Please format the code.

Comment: acceleration data is extremely noisy so it's possible it's over 0.05 even if it's sitting still.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but based on documentation it looks like you're getting gravity + userAcceleration. So it's pretty normal to get non-zero values for y-axis in some device positions.

> The total acceleration of the device is equal to gravity plus the acceleration the user imparts to the device (
>   userAcceleration
>   ).

To get `userAcceleration` you should call `startDeviceMotionUpdates(to:withHandler:)` - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager/1616048-startdevicemotionupdates